# How to make a custom UIViewRepresentable fill its parent VStack and have custom subview centered in it?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiview, uiviewrepresentable

So I have the following in my project.

1. ContentView ~ contains 3 vstacks.
2. CustomView ~ a custom view with a containerView with fixed size of 300x300 that should always be centered in ContentView
3. CustomViewRepresentable ~ a UIViewRepresentable in order to insert CustomView into ContentView.

The code for each is as follows:

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            VStack {
                Color.blue
                    .frame(height: 50)
            }
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Color.green
                        .frame(height: 100)
                    Text("Text")
                    Color.green
                        .frame(height: 100)
                }
            }
            VStack { // content view
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    VStack {
                        CustomViewRepresentable()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                            .background(.gray)
                            .border(.red, width: 1)
                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**CustomView**

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {
    private let containerView = UIView()
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        containerView.center = self.center
    }

    func addContainerView() {
        containerView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.center = self.center
    }
}
```

**CustomViewRepresentable**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct CustomViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = CustomView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomView {
        let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        customView.addContainerView()
        return customView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm facing is that the containerView inside CustomView does not display unless I initialise CustomView with a frame inside the representable.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomView {
        let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
```

I don't understand why this is needed because I'd like the CustomView to take the full width and height of the VStack that it is embedded into. Therefore I figured that just doing

```
CustomViewRepresentable()
   .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
```

inside the VStack should just work, but apparently it does not. So what is the best way for the `CustomViewRepresentable` to fill its parent while keeping the `containerView` always centered within it?

Comment: "unless I initialise CustomView with a frame inside the representable" How else would you initialise it? `let customView = CustomView()` works just as well for me.

Comment: it does not work for me in the sense that if I dont set the frame, the containerView does not show at all.

Comment: What do you mean by " I dont set the frame"? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: inside `makeUIView`, I need to do `let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))` instead of just let `customView = CustomView()`. Only then does the containerView inside the CustomView show.

Comment: Well I cannot reproduce. The container view still appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to provide the `CustomView` frame in `func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomView` function. After replacing `let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))` code with `let customView = CustomView()` working at my end. Please check with the code below.

**ContenView**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            VStack {
                Color.blue
                    .frame(height: 50)
            }
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Color.green
                        .frame(height: 100)
                    Text("Text")
                    Color.green
                        .frame(height: 100)
                }
            }
            VStack { // content view
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    VStack {
                        CustomViewRepresentable()
                            .background(.gray)
                            .border(.red, width: 1)
                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**CustomView**

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {
    private let containerView = UIView()
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        containerView.center = self.center
    }

    func addContainerView() {
        containerView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.center = self.center
    }
}
```

**CustomViewRepresentable**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct CustomViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = CustomView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomView {
        let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        customView.addContainerView()
        return customView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```